# exclude files from triggering a travis ci build on github

Tags: github, travis-ci

Our organization uses `travis-ci` within `github` for basic sanity checking when a change is committed. Is there a way to prevent a full travis build/run when changes to specific files or file types are made?

As the simplest example:  if someone makes a change to the README.md file and wants to commit directly to master, we don't need to do a CI run before allowing this.

Comment: Ref https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6745

Comment: Corresponding Travis CI GitHub issue for reference: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6301

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might instruct your team to add `[skip ci]` to your commit messages, e.g.

`git commit -m "updated readme [skip ci]"`.

This means that this Github commit (after it is pushed) will not trigger a Travis-CI run.

The alternative is to accept that a commit triggers a Travis-CI run, but then simply do condition checks inside your `.travis.yml` (or scripts executed by it) to exclude processing of unit-tests, etc.
In other words: there will be a CI run, but all heavy script stuff could be skipped.